# custom filtering in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, filter

Hi i want to add custom filtering for my jqgrid and i have tried doing the following.

```
filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [{ field: "CityID", op: "eq", data: cityId }, { field: "SiteID", op: "eq", data: siteId }, { field: "BuildingID", op: "eq", data: buildingId }, Last Field Something Like this==>>{field: "ReturnDate" , op:'IsNull'}] };
```

all is fine but i need to figure out how to use the last filter where i need the operator to check if the `ReturnDate` is not null
Basically i want to further add another filter that will narrow down my search and show in the grid only those rows in which the `ReturnDate` is null pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation `"IS NULL"` will be encoded in the filter as `"nu"`.